# limitTo in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am unable to find any example of how to use limitTo to chop one string

```
using like this:
{{'abcdefg' | limitTo:2:5}}
output:
cde
```

I tried the same but getting error:-

```
The pipe 'limitTo' could not be found ("oject of Projects">
```

Comment: Slice is not I want, slice will remove char from start

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/SlicePipe-class.html has an `start` and an `end` argument. Seems to be exactly what you want.